# Does react-select support maxlength in search?

Tags: react-select

There's no mention of it in the docs it seems, I would like to limit the search to n characters.

I can successfully try this in Chrome dev tools by adding a `maxlength` attribute to the input element, but I'm not sure how to tell a react-select component to do that.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna answer myself. You can use `inputProps` which will be passed through to the input element.

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore, it looks like.

Answer (score 7):

Since react-select v2 `inputProps` prop no longer exist. In react-select v2+ you should use [Components API](https://react-select.com/components). In this case code may looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const Input = props => <components.Input {...props} maxLength={5} />;

export default () => (
  <Select
    ...
    components={{ Input }}
    ...
  />
);
```

Comment: I'm using react-select 5.2.2 and this approach has side effect on messing with border-color when focus/blur. after you select something, and click outside the element, the border-color is not changed

Answer (score 5):

this is how you can apply maxLength

pass `maxLength` as a prop or define in your file

```
<Select
...
onInputChange={inputValue =>
            (inputValue.length <= maxLength ? inputValue : inputValue.substr(0, maxLength))
          }
....
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your select component, you can put it like below

```
import { components } from "react-select"

<AsyncSelect
  className="form-control p-0"
  placeholder="Search.."
  components={{
    Input: (props) => (
      <components.Input {...props} maxLength={50} />
    ),
  }}
/>
```